# Shadowbox - Fitting the size to a form/table/div

Tags: php, forms, shadowbox

I am trying to display a form inside a shadowbox but am having some difficulty getting the size of the shadowbox correct. Basically I have a separate PHP file that contains all the code for just the form (which contains a table).

I can open the form inside of a shadowbox just fine, however I can't get the shadowbox to be the exact size of the form. I can manually set the width/height (in pixels) of the box, but I know this will cause problems for viewers with different browsers/resolution settings.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran across your problem when looking to do something else with Shadowbox, and I think I may have accidentally found your answer [here](http://shadowbox-js.com/forum.html#nabble-td2651638). Not sure if that helps or not...